# How do I get the NextVal from an oracle Sequence thru NHibernate

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, sequence, nextval

I am working on c# .net 4.0 and using NHibernate to talk with an Oracle DB. 
You would think something as simple as this is already addressed somewhere but sadly its not.
I need the NextVal from an Oracle sequence.
I do not need to insert it a database as part of an Id or Primary key.
I just need to use the next val on the c# side.

**Can somebody help me out with xml mapping and C# file(or a link) to achieve this.**

Thanks.

Something like

```
int NextValueOfSequence = GetNextValueofSequence();

public int GetNextValueOfSequence()
{

// Access NHibernate to return the next value of the sequence.

}
```

Comment: Cant you just run a max on the Id property and then add 1 to it?

Comment: No. Just assume that the DB has no tables, no SPs , nothing at all but an oracle sequence. I need to get the nextval and use it on the c# side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mapping:

```
  <sql-query name="GetSequence" read-only="true">
    <return-scalar type="Int64"/>
    <![CDATA[
    SELECT SeqName.NEXTVAL from DUAL;
    ]]>
  </sql-query>
```

Code:

```
Int64 nextValue = session.GetNamedQuery("GetSequence").UniqueResult<System.Int64>();
```

Comment: Thanks, I did get some syntax errors in the mapping. Due to time constraints I could not get down to investigating/fixing them. I ended up using...............<your session variable>.CreateSQLQuery("select <your sequence>.NEXTVAL from dual").UniqueResult<Int64>();

Comment: But thanks for your input, it helped me change my course to SQL instead of searching all over for a standard nhibernate mapping/domain class solution.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the answer. There should be "return-scalar" in the mapping.

Comment: your answer (now) requires column="nextId" or some value, and the select needs "as nextId" as well. @gopal added a separate answer below. Have to give him credit. :)

Answer (score 5):

This also does the trick.

```
 <your session variable>.CreateSQLQuery("select <your sequence>.NEXTVAL from dual").UniqueResult<Int64>();
```

Answer (score 5):

With NH4 I use this DB agnostic ISession extension method (obviously DB must support sequences)

```
public static T GetSequenceNextValue<T>(this ISession session, string sequenceName) where T : struct
{
    var dialect = session.GetSessionImplementation().Factory.Dialect;
    var sqlQuery = dialect.GetSequenceNextValString(sequenceName);
    return session.CreateSQLQuery(sqlQuery).UniqueResult<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a small correction in the mapping given by @Petr Kozelek

```
<sql-query name="GetSequence" read-only="true">
    <return-scalar column="NextNo" type="Int64"/>
    <![CDATA[
        SELECT SeqName.NEXTVAL as NextNo from DUAL
    ]]>
</sql-query>
```